# Typescript undefined this. type

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, typescript, ionic-framework

For a assignment we need to make a thermostat app. Me and my group would like to do this in the ionic framework. With some help I've been able to get the api.js we were provided with working in ionic up to some point. But now I've ran into an error that I don't know how to fix.

This is the new API.ts:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//import * as http from '@angular/http';

export class API {
  ServerUrl = '';

  Type = {
    Day: 'day',
    Night: 'night'
  };

  Days = {
    Monday: 'Monday',
    Tuesday: 'Tuesday',
    Wednesday: 'Wednesday',
    Thursday: 'Thursday',
    Friday: 'Friday',
    Saturday: 'Saturday',
    Sunday: 'Sunday'
  };

  MinTemperature = parseFloat('5.0');
  MaxTemperature = parseFloat('30.0');
  MaxSwitches = 5;

  Time;
  CurrentDay;
  DayTemperature;
  NightTemperature;
  CurrentTemperature;
  TargetTemperature;
  ProgramState;

  Program:any = {};

  constructor() {
    this.Program[this.Days.Monday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Tuesday]   = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Wednesday] = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Thursday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Friday]    = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Saturday]  = [];
    this.Program[this.Days.Sunday]    = [];
  }

  /* Retrieve day program
   */
  getProgram(day) {
    return this.Program[day];
  }

  /* Sorts the heating periods (the periods when the heating is on) and merges overlapping ones
   */
  sortMergeProgram(day) {
    let program = this.getProgram(day);
    program.sort(function(a, b) {
      return this.parseTime(a[0]) - this.parseTime(b[0])
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < program.length - 1; i++) {
      if (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) >= this.parseTime(program[i + 1][0])) {
        let start = (program[i][0]);
        let end = (this.parseTime(program[i][1]) > this.parseTime(program[i + 1][1])) ? program[i][1] : program[i + 1][1];
        program.splice(i, 2);
        program.push([start, end]);
        this.sortMergeProgram(day);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  /* Retrieves all data from the server except for weekProgram
   */
  get(attribute_name) {
    return this.requestData(
      "/" + attribute_name,
      function(data) {
        return $(data).text();
      }
    );
  }

  /* Retrieves the week program
   */
  getWeekProgram() {
    return this.requestData(
      '/weekProgram',
      function(data) {
        $(data).find('day').each(function() {
          let day = (<any>$(this)).attr('name');
          this.Program[day] = [];
          $(this).find('switch').each(function() {
            if ((<any>$(this)).attr('state') == 'on') {
              if ((<any>$(this)).attr('type') == this.Type.Day) {
                this.getProgram(day).push([$(this).text(), '00:00']);
              } else {
                this.getProgram(day)[this.getProgram(day).length - 1][1] = $(this).text();
              }
            }
          })
        });
        return this.Program;
      }
    );
  }

  /* Uploads all data to the server except for currentTemperature and weekProgram
   */
  put(attribute_name, xml_tag, value) {
    this.uploadData("/" + attribute_name, "<" + xml_tag + ">" + value + "</" + xml_tag + ">");
  }

  requestData(address, func) {
    let result;
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        result = func(data);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  /* Uploads the week program
   */
  setWeekProgram() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;
      let periods = this.getProgram(key);
      for (i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
        daySwitches.push(periods[i][0]);
        nightSwitches.push(periods[i][1]);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);

        if (i < daySwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(daySwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);

        if (i < nightSwitches.length) {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'on');
          text = doc.createTextNode(nightSwitches[i]);
        } else {
          sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
          text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        }
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }
      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  /* Creates the default week program
   */
  setDefault() {
    let doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
    let program = doc.createElement('week_program');
    program.setAttribute('state', this.ProgramState ? 'on' : 'off');
    for (let key in this.Program) {
      let day = doc.createElement('day');
      day.setAttribute('name', key);

      let daySwitches = [];
      let nightSwitches = [];

      let i, text, sw;

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Night);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < this.MaxSwitches; i++) {
        sw = doc.createElement('switch');
        sw.setAttribute('type', this.Type.Day);
        sw.setAttribute('state', 'off');
        text = doc.createTextNode('00:00');
        sw.appendChild(text);
        day.appendChild(sw);
      }

      program.appendChild(day);
    }
    doc.appendChild(program);
    this.uploadData('/weekProgram', (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));
  }

  uploadData(address, xml) {
    (<any>$).ajax({
      type: "put",
      url: this.ServerUrl + address,
      contentType: 'application/xml',
      data: xml,
      async: false
    });
  }

  parseTime(t) {
    return parseFloat(t.substr(0, 2)) + parseFloat(t.substr(3, 2)) / 60;
  }

  /* Adds a heating period for a specific day
   */
  addPeriod(day, start, end) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    program.push([start, end]);
    this.sortMergeProgram(day);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Removes a heating period from a specific day.
     idx is the idex of the period with values from 0 to 4
  */
  removePeriod(day, idx) {
    let program = this.getWeekProgram()[day];
    let start = program[idx][0];
    let end = program[idx][1];
    program.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setWeekProgram();
  }

  /* Checks whether the temperature is within the range [5.0,30.0]
   */
  inTemperatureBoundaries(temp) {
    temp = parseFloat(temp);
    return (temp >= this.MinTemperature && temp <= this.MaxTemperature);
  }
}
```

The function I'm having a problem with is `getWeekProgram()` it is retrieving the weekProgram just fine from the server that was provided. But this server is sending XML-responses (no way to get JSON...) and when the line `this.Program[day] = []` is ran I get the following error: `Runtime Error, this.Program[day] is undefined`. I have no clue on how to fix this error.. I've tried removing the line, and tried making the Program into a big array instead of an object but nothing is working sadly ;/.

This is the XML-data we're working with:

```
<week_program state="off">
  <day name="Monday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Tuesday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Wednesday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Thursday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Friday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Saturday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
  <day name="Sunday">
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="night" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
    <switch type="day" state="off">00:00</switch>
  </day>
</week_program>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various `this` references inside the inner functions do not refer to the class instance. The current `this` is not carried into functions when the function is declared using the `function(){...}` syntax; to do that you need to use this syntax: `()=>{...}`. You can read more about how `this` behaves [in the TypeScript wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this-in-TypeScript).

However, in your case, you don't want to use the `()=>{...}` syntax either because you depend on `this` to refer to the items being processed by `.each`. So you need to manually save the class instance `this` in a different variable on the outside. A common name for such variables is `self`:

```
  getWeekProgram() {
    let self = this;
    return this.requestData(
      '/weekProgram',
      function(data) {
        $(data).find('day').each(function() {
          let day = (<any>$(this)).attr('name');
          self.Program[day] = [];
          $(this).find('switch').each(function() {
            if ((<any>$(this)).attr('state') == 'on') {
              if ((<any>$(this)).attr('type') == self.Type.Day) {
                self.getProgram(day).push([$(this).text(), '00:00']);
              } else {
                self.getProgram(day)[self.getProgram(day).length - 1][1] = $(this).text();
              }
            }
          })
        });
        return self.Program;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this indeed works!! The api is fully working now ;D Thanks a lot!! Now we can finally start on the design part (which is what this whole subject is about....)